# Need to sort a large amount of coordinates into different regions of the UK, ideally into irregularly-shaped regions rather than grids, any advice?

Tags: r, excel

So there are about 65000 long/lat coordinates and I need to find what regions they are all in, but I'm unsure of how to do this with non-grid regions, as I could sort those easily enough just by working out the bounds, however I'm really unsure how to do it for polygon-shaped regions as there are no simple bounds due to the irregular shape, so I'm hoping someone has had experience with this type of problem!

Ideally I would be working either in Excel or with R, unless some software already exists for this exact problem!

Comment: What you're describing is a spatial join. You can do it in R (e.g. with `st_join()` from the [sf package](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/)) or any GIS software, spatial database, etc.

Comment: So would that involve finding shape data for the regions? and how can I then get the region to be added to that coordinate in the original excel spreadsheet?